# A href through $ variable javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, hyperlink

So I am trying to get the firebase link that the user has provided and make it a clickable link. I have this so far

```
<li>
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">${forum.title}</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white">
        ${forum.content} <br />
        <p>${forum.link}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to make forum.link clickable but don't know how to add a href before a variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<div class="collapsible-body white">     
    ${forum.content} <br/> 
    <p> 
    <a href="${forum.link}">Link Description</a>
    </p> 
</div>
```